# Import webpack externals package in TypeScript with local declaration file

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-externals, declaration-files

I'm trying to import an external module in my typescript module. In the environment of the web app there already is a module loader and the module "my-lib" is present, which is written in JavaScript and does not ship with a declaration file.

So, I want to require this lib, but have the module declaration locally (as I am the only one currently using TypeScript in this context).

I tried to set the search path for the declaration file using `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`. This worked for `/// <reference types="my-lib" />`, but didn't for `import "my-lib";`. Only if I put the `@types` folder inside the `node_modules` folder the module resolution would find and import it.

Is there any way to set it up, such that I don't need to put `@types` inside the `node_modules` folder?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

@types/my-lib/index.d.ts:

```
interface MyLib {
    ...
}

declare const myLib: MyLib;
export = myLib;
```

src/entry.ts:

```
import myLib from "my-lib";
...
```

webpack.config.js:

```
...
externals: {
    "my-lib": "my-lib"
},
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I made it with the following `tsconfig.json` (just came to my mind):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./@types"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "*",
                "@types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "@types/**/*"
    ]
}
```